# Custom Action to copy a file in msi

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.11

In my msi, I want to copy a file (which is add to msi project) to install location using Custom Action.

```
<CustomAction Id="Copyile"
                   Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                   ExeCommand="cmd /c xcopy /y &quot;.\FIle1.txt&quot; &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]&quot;" Execute="deferred" />
```

I used above custm action to copy  file, but installtion is getting failed because source file is not found because path of .\File1.txt is not resolved

Comment: What is the reason that you don't use [CopyFile](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html)?

Comment: It is usually better to generate such files on application launch - potentially from read-only template files installed by the setup.